# GUI opens with Rstudio but not from command prompt using Rscript

Tags: r, rjava

Am trying to call R GUI script in java swing using `rjava` from windows10 command prompt. When I run the script it runs fine in Rstudio but when I run in the command prompt using R script the GUI window does not appear

The code written in java , I have called from R script and the GUI opens in the R studio but in command prompt using Rscript it does not work

Following is R code

```
library(rJava)
.jinit()
.jclassPath()
x <- .jnew("HelloJava1")
x$test()
```

Following is java swing code

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class HelloJava1 extends JComponent {

public void test() {
        Runnable r = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            JFrame f = new JFrame("HelloJava1");
            // f.setSize(300, 300);  better to pack() the frame
            f.getContentPane().add(new HelloJava1());
            // pack should be AFTER components are added..
            f.pack();
            f.setVisible(true);
        }
      };
     // Swing GUIs should be created and updated on the EDT
     SwingUtilities.invokeLater(r);
     }    

@Override  // good practice..
    public void paintComponent(java.awt.Graphics g) {
    // always call super method 1st!
       super.paintComponent(g);
       g.drawString("Hello, Java!", 125, 95);
     }

// instead of setting the size of components, it is 
// better to override the preferred size.
@Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
      return new Dimension(300,300);
    }
  }
```

Following is the code using command prompt

```
D:\Esurveyingsofttech\elevation>"C:\Program Files\R\R-3.6.1\bin\x64\Rscript.exe" D:\\Esurveyingsofttech\\elevation\\TestSwingGui.R
```

Java swing code opens a GUI in R studio , similarly when we run using Rscript the GUI should open. Any help is highly appreciated

Comment: it does open ... just closes very quickly. To see add `Sys.sleep(10) ; print("done")` to the end of your R script.

Comment: Thanks ...it is indeed opening the gui very quickly and closing too..